# Smart Contract Lottery throws "VirtualMachineError: revert" when ending the lottery

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, chainlink, brownie

I have been following Solidity, Blockchain, and Smart Contract Course – Beginner to Expert Python Tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M576WGiDBdQ&t=28658s). When I run deploy_lottery.py, it breaks down while ending the lottery. Here is the snippet of code in Lottery.sol

```
function endLottery() public onlyOwner {
        lottery_state = LOTTERY_STATE.CALCULATING_WINNER;
        bytes32 requestId = requestRandomness(keyhash, fee);

        emit RequestedRandomness(requestId);
    }
```

Here is the code snippet in deploy_lottery.py

```
def end_lottery():
    account = get_account()
    lottery = Lottery[-1]
    # fund the contract
    # then end the lottery

    tx = fund_with_link(lottery.address)
    tx.wait(1)
    print("Here")
    ending_transaction = lottery.endLottery({"from": account})
    print("ended transaction")
    ending_transaction.wait(1)
    time.sleep(180)
    print(f"{lottery.recentWinner()} is the new winner!")
```

I have also attached snapshot of error. Thanks in advance.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yU8jC.png

Comment: did you use the original code from GitHub?

Comment: I have the same problem!

Comment: No, I followed Patrick as he coded in the video. I also checked all the github files line by line.

Answer (score 1):

I have been stuck with the same error. The solution was to fund the contract with sufficient token. For testing I did
amount=5000000000000000000 in fund_with_link()

```
def fund_with_link(contract_address, account=None, link_token=None, amount=5000000000000000000): 
    account = account if account else get_account() 
    link_token = link_token if link_token else get_contract("link_token") 
    tx = link_token.transfer(contract_address, amount, {"from": account}) 
    tx.wait(1) 
    print("Contract Funded") 
    return tx
```

Comment: 'def fund_with_link(contract_address, account=None, link_token=None, amount=5000000000000000000):
    account = account if account else get_account()
    link_token = link_token if link_token else get_contract("link_token")
    tx = link_token.transfer(contract_address, amount, {"from": account})
    tx.wait(1)
    print("Contract Funded")
    return tx
'

Comment: So you simply need to fund the transaction and that funding should be more than the fee of VRFCoordinator